# Issues in the values in numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy

The output numpy array of my program looks like this:

```
[0.8500000000000001, 0.9000000000000001, 0.8800000000000001, 0.875]
```

However, I want to get them as;

```
0.85,0.9,0.88,0.875
```

Any idea, why that happens and how to get rid of it?

Comment: floating-point arithmetic is imprecise.

Comment: How can I get rid of it?

Comment: You can't if you are using floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You can if you are using *decimal* floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well, you can get rid of this particular example of imprecision, but imprecision remains with decimal floating point arithmetic, no?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In general, yes, like when you compute 1/3. But those numbers look to me like they were created in a way such that using decimals would've prevented the problem.